# Why is my canvasjs chart not loading?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. My chart doesn't render at all.

this is the JSON data that the service is returning. 
[{"label":"A","y":0},{"label":"B","y":5},{"label":"C","y":2},{"label":"D","y":0},{"label":"T","y":7}][{"label":"A","y":0},{"label":"B","y":5},{"label":"C","y":2},{"label":"D","y":0},{"label":"T","y":7}]
[{"label":"A","y":0},{"label":"B","y":10},{"label":"C","y":4},{"label":"D","y":0},{"label":"T","y":14}]

here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
       $(document).ready(function () {

       $.getJSON('data.php', function (result) {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart('Container', {
        title:{
            text: 'Results of Survey',
        },
        data: [

        {
            type: 'column',
            dataPoints: result

        }

        ]

    });

    chart.render();

    });



    });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="Container" style="width: 800px; height: 380px;"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it's not displaying anything. and there is no JS errors. the JSON  data is from my data.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is malformed.  If you are trying to do multi-series, see this doc:

http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/multi-series-charts/

This:

```
    [{"label":"A","y":0},{"label":"B","y":5},{"label":"C","y":2},{"label":"D","y":0},{"label":"T","y":7}]
[{"label":"A","y":0},{"label":"B","y":5},{"label":"C","y":2},{"label":"D","y":0},{"label":"T","y":7}] 
[{"label":"A","y":0},{"label":"B","y":10},{"label":"C","y":4},{"label":"D","y":0},{"label":"T","y":14}]
```

Should be:

```
[{"label":"A","y":0},{"label":"B","y":5},{"label":"C","y":2},{"label":"D","y":0},{"label":"T","y":7},{"label":"A","y":0},{"label":"B","y":5},{"label":"C","y":2},{"label":"D","y":0},{"label":"T","y":7},{"label":"A","y":0},{"label":"B","y":10},{"label":"C","y":4},{"label":"D","y":0},{"label":"T","y":14}]
```

You have repeating column labels though which is why I mentioned the docs above.  Are you trying to do multiple series instead of a column chart?

Edit:

This code displays your data fine assuming you are doing a straight column chart:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        title:{
            text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"              
        },
        data: [              
        {
            // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
            type: "column",
            dataPoints:  [{"label":"A","y":0},{"label":"B","y":5},{"label":"C","y":2},{"label":"D","y":0},{"label":"T","y":7},{"label":"A","y":0},{"label":"B","y":5},{"label":"C","y":2},{"label":"D","y":0},{"label":"T","y":7},{"label":"A","y":0},{"label":"B","y":10},{"label":"C","y":4},{"label":"D","y":0},{"label":"T","y":14}]
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey, thank you. you're right.  I was  trying to do multiple series instead of a column chart. how can I do multiple series?

Comment: Updated answer with docs for multiple series.  You will have to loop through your JSON object to create the appropriate format or modify your php file to return the proper format.